# LangDetectException No features in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a script that detects the language of incomming text (which are in bulk) with the help of langdetect module.I also have set an email alert script for error so when I get an error a mail will be sent to me. my problem is that whenever langdetect is not able to recognise a language (that happens a lot of time as I get many random texts from internet) it throws an exception "No Features in Text". Due to this my daily email sending capacity gets exhausted. What I want is for it to check if the error is for no features in text then it will skip the sending email part else it will send email.
How can I do this?

```
I tried using if case:
if LangDetectException.code == 'no features in text':
 pass
else:
 sendmail()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it usingget_code method as follows

```
if error.get_code() == 5:
  pass
else:
  sendmail()
```

5 is for no features in text.
Thank you